# RegEx to check URL syntax

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to verify the syntax and pattern of a URL before it is used for testing. Regex is not my forte, however I thought it would be fairly simple.

The url pattern is a follows tcp://serverName:port/SearchServer

What I have tried is this. However it fails what should be a valid syntax
`String regex = "(tcp:\\/\\/)?[A-Za-z0-9]?" + "/^:/$" + "[0-9]?" + "/^/SearchServer$/";`

Comment: Do you have to use a regular expression?  `"/SearchServer".equals(new URI(string).getPath())` will check for a valid URI syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you can start with:

```java
final String regex = "((tcp|http|https):\\/\\/)?[\\w.]+(:\\d+)\\/[\\/\\w]*";
final String string = "tcp://serverName:8080/SearchServer";
```

so you optionally have the `protocol` with `://`,
followed by mix of letters and `.`, optional `:port` and then a mix of letters and `/`

there are more things to add, but this is a good start :)